# Count Is Not Working With LEFT Join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables shown below:

First is `Product` 
[image]

And the second one is `Documents`
[image]

I just want the count of documents for each records of `Product` table but it only gives one row. I have used the following query:

```
SELECT `p`.`Id`,
       `p`.`Name`,
       `u`.`FirstName`,
       `u`.`LastName`,
       Count(doc.Id) AS NumOfDocuments
FROM (`Product` AS p)
LEFT JOIN `Documents` AS doc ON `p`.`Id` = `doc`.`ProductId`
INNER JOIN `ProductXUsers` AS pu ON `pu`.`ProductId` = `p`.`Id`
INNER JOIN `Users` AS u ON `u`.`Id` = `pu`.`UserId`
AND u.UserType='Customer'
WHERE `p`.`CreatedBy` = '3'
GROUP BY p.Id
```

Comment: It looks like your inner joins and/or where clause condition are eliminating the second row you expected to see.

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY` in your query and you can just remove the parentheses enclosing **`Product AS p`**:

```
SELECT `p`.`Id`,
       `p`.`Name`,
       `u`.`FirstName`,
       `u`.`LastName`,
       Count(doc.Id) AS NumOfDocuments
FROM `Product` AS p
LEFT JOIN `Documents` AS doc ON `p`.`Id` = `doc`.`ProductId`
INNER JOIN `ProductXUsers` AS pu ON `pu`.`ProductId` = `p`.`Id`
INNER JOIN `Users` AS u ON `u`.`Id` = `pu`.`UserId`
AND u.UserType='Customer'
WHERE `p`.`CreatedBy` = '3'
GROUP BY p.Id,`p`.`Name`,`u`.`FirstName`,`u`.`LastName`
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you used p.Name in group by

Comment: Read the article in this site: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, you can use `IFNULL` to replace the `null` values.

```
SELECT `p`.`Id`,
       `p`.`Name`,
       `u`.`FirstName`,
       `u`.`LastName`,
       IFNULL(Count(doc.Id),0) AS NumOfDocuments
FROM `Product` AS p
INNER JOIN `ProductXUsers` AS pu ON `pu`.`ProductId` = `p`.`Id`
INNER JOIN `Users` AS u ON `u`.`Id` = `pu`.`UserId` AND u.UserType='Customer'
LEFT JOIN `Documents` AS doc ON `p`.`Id` = `doc`.`ProductId`
WHERE `p`.`CreatedBy` = '3'
GROUP BY p.Id
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you used p.Name in group by?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com: Grouping by p.Name is not mandatory. Can you show some sample data?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com: Are you getting only one row even after grouping by the result? Then it will be a problem with the data in your table.